# How to report if input is sanitized with OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer

Tags: java, html, owasp

I see in the API that it's possible but I can't figure out [how to use that sanitize() method](https://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/20160628.1/index.html?org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html). There's even a [forum post where someone says to use it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-support/y-1WwAfb3K4) but they don't explain how. In essence I have no idea what `CTX` means in that method signature. If someone can provide sample code of how to get a list of items that were sanitized that would be appreciated.

Comment: `CTX` is a generic type in the method.

Comment: I understand that but I'm still unsure how to use it...

Comment: You said "I have no idea what `CTX` means in that method signature.", now you say "I understand that". Which is it?

Comment: The question is how do you use the method? There's no sample code to look at...

Comment: What about that sample code right in the beginning of your first link? The one titled **Usage**?

Comment: HtmlSanitizer.sanitize(myHtml, policy.apply(myHtmlStreamRenderer)); But where's the list of items that were sanitized?

Comment: Is there supposed to be one?

Comment: Ok I think I just figured it out. Basically you have to you can set the context on the listener to be a List<String> which you can then populate. I'm answering the question below and you can tell me if I did it correctly or not.

Comment: @Kayaman Do you happen know where I can find code to also embed an image in base64? I can't seem to get it to work either. I posted at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345392/how-to-allow-embedded-images-when-sanitizing-html-with-owasp-java-html-sanitizer

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the `HtmlChangeListener` to catch all elements that are sanitized. The code then looks something like:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

HtmlChangeListener<List<String>> htmlChangeListener = new HtmlChangeListener<>()
{
    @Override
    public void discardedTag(List<String> context, String elementName)
    {
        context.add(elementName);
    }

    @Override
    public void discardedAttributes(List<String> context, String tagName, String... attributeNames)
    {
        context.add(tagName);
    }
};

String sanitizedHtml = POLICY_DEFINITION.sanitize(rawHtml, htmlChangeListener, results);
System.out.println("Sanitized elements include: " + String.join(",", results));
```

Comment: It should be StringUtils.join()