# How to allow embedded images when sanitizing html with OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer

Tags: java, html, owasp

I would like to allow:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,..."/>
```

I see [there's documentation on how to do this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project#tab=Inline_2FEmbedded_Images) but I don't understand how to implement it. I tried to add the pattern

```
.allowUrlProtocols("data")
.allowAttributes("src").matching(Pattern.compile("$data:image.*")).onElements("img")
```

But that didn't work. I understand the pattern must be a regex expression but I'm not sure I understand how it all links up. I get that it's trying to look for img tags and then looks at the src attribute. My understanding is that it should then look for the string data:image and if finds that allows it through. But that's not happening...

Comment: / needs to be escaped with \/

Comment: Thinking it was some kind of related issue I tried to remove the / but that nonetheless didn't allow the element. I just removed the / from the question to show that this wasn't the issue. But good catch.

Comment: Just an FYI I also tried contains just data, as in /data/ but that didn't work either. Therefore even just a basic regex is not working or the above setup code is wrong...

Comment: You might want to try `$data:image.*` as the pattern.

Comment: I tried adding ^.*data.*$ but either way they both failed... Also just to let you know I'm using the ebay example policy and just added those two lines. Since it's allow versus deny it shouldn't matter if another allowAttribute overlaps...

Comment: When debugging the code it seems to put "data:image..." as an attribute in the list of attributes, the same as src. Therefore when it's iterating through the attributes there are no policies for "data:image...". But I could also be interpreting the code incorrectly...

Comment: Breakthrough! It appears the policies only check the first allowAttribute and ignore the others. In other words it's not compounded. You have to OR the predicate in the matching clause.

Answer (score 8):

If you got here (like I did) but you are using the HTMLSanitizer for C#, then the answer is:

```
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
sanitizer.AllowedSchemes.Add("data");
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that I had:

```
private static final PolicyFactory POLICY_DEFINITION = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowUrlProtocols("data")
    .allowAttributes("src").matching(ONSITE_OR_OFFSITE_URL).onElements("img")
    .allowAttributes("src").matching(Pattern.compile("^.*data:image/.*$")).onElements("img")
    .toFactory();
```

This caused an issue in that I assumed `allowAttribute` would combine both. Instead what you have to do is OR the pattern matching (for whatever pattern you want to match) as in:

```
Pattern EMBEDDED_IMAGE = Pattern.compile("^.*data:image/.*$")
ONSITE_OR_OFFSITE_URL_OR_EMBEDDED_IMAGE = matchesEither(ONSITE_URL, OFFSITE_URL, EMBEDDED_IMAGE);

private static final PolicyFactory POLICY_DEFINITION = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowUrlProtocols("data")
    .allowAttributes("src").matching(ONSITE_OR_OFFSITE_URL_OR_EMBEDDED_IMAGE).onElements("img")
    .toFactory();
```

This code assumes you're using the [EbayPolicyExample](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/examples/EbayPolicyExample.java)

Comment: Good but doesn't work to combine 3 params as matchesEither in the Ebay Policy Example only takes 2 params.

Comment: Note that there's no point using `^` to anchor the beginning of the pattern if you immediately follow it with `.*`.