# Sanitize Html with base64 image (and convert it to an image)

Tags: base64, tinymce, owasp, html-sanitizing

I have a WebApp with a TinyMCE Html Editor that allows users to input some html from a web page. Images can be pasted and are encoded as base64.
Before saving the user input to DB I use [OWASP java-html-sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project) to discard potential dangerous code (javascript,...).

Some characters in the base64 string of the image are escaped and when I try to get the image back (using apache commons Base64) I'm not able to get a valid image.

Here my code for decoding the image:

```
byte[] b;
String s = html;
b = s.getBytes(Utility.UTF8);
b = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(b);
```

For the HtmlSanitizer I have done nothing special, just followed the [Ebay Policy Example](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/master/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/examples/EbayPolicyExample.java) allowing base64 images as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345392/how-to-allow-embedded-images-when-sanitizing-html-with-owasp-java-html-sanitizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-support/decode%7Csort:date/owasp-java-html-sanitizer-support/3xtlfI3tkA4/A-iFt5gRBAAJ) I need "to HTML decode before base64 decoding".

I have tried with apache common StringEscapeUtils:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(html);
```

and it's working. Great.

Answer (score 0):

`allowedSchemes: [ 'data']` or `allowedSchemesByTag: { img: [ 'data' ]}` can be used to allow `img` tag to accept/allow base64.